# Jittering background images when scrolling in IE

Tags: scroll, internet-explorer-11

I have been working on a one-page parallax test-site and I have been struggling with jittering or shaking images in IE11 when scrolling. This is the website : http://magzim.atwebpages.com/

It works fine in Mozilla and Chrome. I have tried the following sollutions based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219172/stuttering-background-image-ie) and other answers relating to this question. Without any positive result.

1) diable horizontal scrolling

2) reduce image size

3) diable smooth scrolling in advanced options

4) The problem could be solved by changing the 'position' of the divs to 'fixed'. But then I would have to change my entire script as it relies on the images being 'relative'.

The **weird** thing is: When I 'inspect an element' using the "developer tools" equivalent for IE11 (called DOM-explorer?) the jittering stops!!!! So activating the DOM-explorer prevents the shaking of the divs when scrolling!

Can someone please help me fix this without me having to completely rewrite my script?

Thanks!

Magzim

Comment: Looks like Microsoft are aware of how bad their browser is: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/819518/fixed-background-image-scrolling-issue  https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806682/fixed-background-image-jumps-up-and-down-during-scroll

Answer (score 0):

### javascript to prevent shaking background images when scrolling in Internet Explorer

This is a javascript for disabling smooth scroll. Put it in the head section or at the bottom of the body section in your html code.

[Demo](https://www.terrafertile.gr/)

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wd = event.wheelDelta;
    var csp = window.pageYOffset;
    window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little to the answer to explain what it does and how it answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

### javascript to prevent shaking background images when scrolling in Internet Explorer

This is a javascript for disabling smooth scroll. Put the script inside a script tag in the head section or at the bottom of the body section in your html code.

[Demo](https://www.terrafertile.gr/)

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
  document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wd = event.wheelDelta;
    var csp = window.pageYOffset;
    window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
  });
}
```